# Does the tradition of writing Rama Koti have any scriptural basis?

Tags: scripture, history, rama

Rama Koti is a practice in Hinduism in which a devotee of Rama writes the name of Rama in a book for one crore times.

Is this tradition of writing rama koti mentioned anywhere in the scriptures or is it of historical origin?